# * Active Users Discrepency in Firebase/BigQuery*

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, mobile-application

I have came across a problem in bigQuery and it's not making sense to me how is this possible. So scenario here is that we are upgrading/releasing our app to newer version and seeing how many active users we have on the newest/latest version that we released. I'm measuring this number (Unique Active users) using 'user_engagement' event (Definition of AUs from Firebase). Now here comes the problem. This number 'Active Users' should be equal to Number of Users (Who installed the app of latest version + People who upgraded the app to latest version). But there is huge difference between stats from these 2 sources.

The unique number of users' that I'm getting via 'user_engagement' is far greater than that of from (first_open and app_update)
Number difference is in thousands

**First Query**

```sql
SELECT 
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as new_users_on_app_version 
FROM TABLE 
where event_name IN ('first_open','app_update') 
  AND app_info.version = '5.8.1' 
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190515' AND '20190527'
```

**Second Query**

```sql
SELECT 
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as active_users_on_app_version 
FROM TABLE 
where event_name = 'user_engagement' 
  AND app_info.version = '5.8.1' 
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190515' AND '20190527' 
  ##Note: 20190515 is the data when we released the new version 5.8.1
```

Comment: Can you share your queries, please?

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann FIRST QUERY
SELECT count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as new_users_on_app_version FROM TABLE
where event_name IN ('first_open','app_update') AND app_info.version = '5.8.1'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190515' AND '20190527'
------------------------------------------------------------------
SECOND QUERY
SELECT count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as active_users_on_app_version FROM TABLE
where event_name = 'user_engagement' AND app_info.version = '5.8.1'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190515' AND '20190527'

##Note: 20190515 is the data when we released the new version 5.8.1

Comment: Update --
I have sampled some of users events data to study transition of app version to latest one. And surprised to see that app_update is missing when app version changes in events data from BigQuery. That's the reason of this discrepency I guess.